# getting input values from javascript in bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml

First of all I'm no javascript expert at all, actually I am totally new to javascript. The function I use is copy pasted and edited, so I am rly not into this. For some how I can not figure out how to resolve the input text from that form. 
Javascript code:

```
function addInput(type) {
     // Create an input type dynamically.
     var element = document.createElement("input");
     // Assign different attributes to the element.
     element.setAttribute("type", "text");
     //element.setAttribute("value", type);
     element.setAttribute("name", "text");
     var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
     // Append the element in page (in span).
     foo.appendChild(element);
};
```

The method call in xhtml is :

```
<h:form>
<h:messages infoClass="success" errorClass="error"
    warnStyle="warning" />

<div class="info">
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <h:outputText value=" = #{msg['required']}" />
</div>

<div class="widget box" style="width: 40%; float: left">
    <div class="widget-header">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" /> #{msg['common']}
    </div>
    <div class="widget-content">
        <div class="form_wrapper">
            <label>#{msg['projectname']}:<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <h:inputText class="inputText"
                value="#{projectBean.project.name}" label="#{msg['firstname']}"
                required="true" autocomplete="off" />
            <util:helptext helptext="#{msg['projectname.desc']}" show="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="widget box" style="width: 40%; float: left">
    <div class="widget-header">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" /> #{msg['workpackage']}
    </div>

    <div class="widget-content">
        <label>#{msg['workpackagename']}:</label><br />
            <span id="fooBar"><br /></span> <INPUT type="button" value="Add"
                onclick="addInput()" />

        <div style="clear: left;"></div>

    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
    <h:commandButton id="button" class="button"
        value="#{msg['button.save']}"
        action="#{projectBean.createProject}" />
</div>
</h:form>
```

But how do I get the values of the input text in my bean?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for passing value to bean. In your code already exist `h:inputText` which will do it. You need create proper Java class with getter and setter for property used in `value` attribute of `h:inputText`.